# Как сверстать данный блок с изображением?

Tags: вёрстка

Здавствуйте!
Не знаю как сверстать данный блок, подскажите пожалуйста.
Нужно ли здесь верстать каждую стрелочку или просто вставить изображением?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы сначала задайте вопрос : "зачем это верстать?". Если у вас данное изображение и подписи статичны, то просто вставьте изображение и всё.

Comment: не морочьте себе голову, если дизайнеру важен этот элемент и нужно сэкономить место на сервере, пусть дадут вектор. даже если вы заморочитесь и сверстаете данный элемент, то велика вероятность того, что он  где то да поедет, мобилы, explower

Comment: Если элемент предполагается скриптовать - увеличивать надписи при наведении мышки, анимировать стрелочки: то нужно, иначе нет. А вообще в малой вёрстке/разработке нет правильно/неправильно - есть то, что хочет заказчик, а вы соответственно его желания воплощаете так как проще вам.